# Sqlplus not fetching result from database using bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, unix, sqlplus

I have a file which contains contact details and circle ID, separated by spaces.
I want to query the database, based on the circle ID, which is associated with the number in the file.
Circle wise table names are different, hence I am using case statement, to match against appropriate circle ID, and then query number in that table.

But, I am not getting any output.
Login details are saved in a file db.profile, and I have sourced it in my scripts.
table name depends on circle and date,eg ,i_admin.cdr_c09_Jul_2020,for circle 4 and July month.

Sqlplus logs says, client side initialization of diagnosability framework failed, user missing read, write and exec permission. But, when same query I am running with sql developer application, its running fine and gives output.

###############input file sample content##############

xx690xx049 8 
8xxx235xxx 4 
xx4966xxx1 4

##################Code##############
#!/bin/bash 
. $HOME/.bash_profile 
. /data/profiles/db.profile

date1=`date +%b_%Y`;

home_path="/data/profiles/temp"

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
>&2 echo "illegal number of parameters"
exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "${1}" ]; then
>&2 echo "File ${1} not found"
exit 1
fi

FILE="${1}"
cd ${home_path}

while read line; do
USER=`echo ${line} | cut -d " " -f 1`
circle=`echo ${line} | cut -d " " -f 2`

```
case ${circle} in
    9)
        
        DBConf=$O_Z5
        sqlplus -s ${DBConf}<< EOF >> /${home_path}/LOGS/C${circle}.log
        set serveroutput on;
        select /*+parallel(a,6)*/ * from i_admin.cdr_c09_${date1} a where msisdn="\'$USER\'"  and circle_id=${circle};
        
        exit;
```

EOF
;;

```
    4)
        
        DBConf=$O_Z5
        sqlplus -s ${DBConf}<< EOF >> /${home_path}/LOGS/C${circle}.log
        set serveroutput on;
        select /*+parallel(a,6)*/ * from i_admin.cdr_c04_${date1} a where msisdn="\'$USER\'"  and circle_id=${circle};
        exit;
```

EOF
;;
esac
done<${FILE}

##############sqlnet log file##########

NL-08014: Failed to initialize Diagnosability framework, falling back to old network tracing/logging

NL-08015: Client(OCI) side initialization of Diagnosability framework failed
ORA-48165: user missing read, write, or exec permission on specified ADR Base directory []
User inputted base directory is invalid [48187] [/u01/app/oracle]

NL-08014: Failed to initialize Diagnosability framework, falling back to old network tracing/logging

NL-08015: Client(OCI) side initialization of Diagnosability framework failed
ORA-48165: user missing read, write, or exec permission on specified ADR Base directory []
User inputted base directory is invalid [48187] [/u01/app/oracle]

NL-08014: Failed to initialize Diagnosability framework, falling back to old network tracing/logging

NL-08015: Client(OCI) side initialization of Diagnosability framework failed
ORA-48165: user missing read, write, or exec permission on specified ADR Base directory []
User inputted base directory is invalid [48187] [/u01/app/oracle]

NL-08014: Failed to initialize Diagnosability framework, falling back to old network tracing/logging

NL-08015: Client(OCI) side initialization of Diagnosability framework failed
ORA-48165: user missing read, write, or exec permission on specified ADR Base directory []
User inputted base directory is invalid [48187] [/u01/app/oracle]

NL-08014: Failed to initialize Diagnosability framework, falling back to old network tracing/logging

Comment: Can you add the full error message and paste the code as text instead of a picture?

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding bash/sqlplus and going for a programming language that has libraries for accessing oracle db (java, python, perl...). There are things that can go wrong with connections, authentication, query failure, result formatting...